# Soundcloud API and Custom music player

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to build a Cordova application in which users will post the links to tracks on Soundcloud. Using their API, I ll need to play the track on my custom music player on the application.

There are some points I cant understand from the API -

1. Will the end user need to authenticate to listen to the tracks?
2. The API supports playing the track on the html5 audio element?
3. Can I play any other user's track if I have its link?

Answer (score 0):

1. The end user need not authenticate.
2. Yes it supports html5 audio element.
3. Yes if the track is available to the public.

http://jsbin.com/cevuga